# Extend Entity Framwork add column to IdentiyServer4 clients table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I have a DbContext that is part of Identityserver4 I am quite new to entity-framework.

```
namespace IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.DbContexts 
{
public class ConfigurationDbContext : DbContext, IConfigurationDbContext, IDisposable
{
    public ConfigurationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext> options, ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions);

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IdentityResource> IdentityResources { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApiResource> ApiResources { get; set; }

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
}

namespace IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities
{
public class Client
{
 // I want to add a column here
 ................

}
```

The thing is I would like to Extend the Client class which is basically the clients table in the database and add a new column.   Is this possible?

I am not allowed to edit these files as they are part of the Identityserver4 dlls.  The only thing i can think of would be to create my own db context and copy what IdentityServer does but this just seams like over kill and i am not sure if IdentityServer will be able to read from the new table.

The column in question that i am trying to add to the Client table. Is an app id identifying the third party developer who has is using the client.   We need to be able to contact them in the even there is an issue with their client or what they are doing.  In worst case ban developers who are miss behaving.

Comment: If those properties are going to be stored on the DB then you can: 1-Create a new entity related to the client primary key and retrieve it manually or 2-Download the source code for IdentityServer4 and modify it by your needs.

Comment: By entity you mean DbContext?  I thought the point was to only have one in the application.   *Rather not fork Identityserver4*   I was hoping to just add another column to the client table rather then make a new reference table.

Comment: An entity is a model, `Client` is an entity. Also, DbContexts are intended to be use-and-destroy, each time you need an instance you create a new dbcontext, and you can have as many dbcontext types as you need

Comment: Isn't it an option to add this information as claim in the ClientClaims table. Instead of extending the Client table.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Thats exactly want i want to do but i cant as client is part of IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities.   I cant edit this file without doing as Gusman sugested and forking Identityserver4

Comment: I do not mean an additional column. If you use the store as provided by Ids4 then you'll have one table called ClientClaims. You can insert a record in that table to store the information.

Comment: This column isnt a claim this column is an internal column used to identify the owner of the client. Developers create new clients we need to assassinated the client with the developer / APP which is using it (so we can contact them if they are doing something wrong), think of it as a user id.   Its not a claim for the authenticating user.

Comment: The `Client` class has a `Properties` dictionary that allows you to add client specific values as needed http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/client.html

Comment: @brad that's awesome can't believe I missed it.  Want to post that as an answer I can expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Client` class has a `Properties` dictionary that allows you to add client specific values.

From the docs - http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/client.html

> **Properties** - Dictionary to hold any custom client-specific values as
>   needed.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use this it appears to be part of the 2.0 upgrade on identity server.   I will need to apply this upgrade in the near future